# Generic string is used on localized sites instead of unique for Web presence fields errors on profile settings page

Tags: bug, profile-page, localization, russian-stackoverflow, transifex

Error on en SO:

> [image]

Same error on ru SO:

> [image]

Strings from Transifex:

> [image]

Looks like En SO uses strings with keys: `24fcebcdd33add36a026175fcc6b8f74` (for Github) and `69a340efb2d565ff161c9b5dd45e9c38`  (for Twitter).

And Ru SO uses generic string with key `cb283c14f539f13da940430e798a29aa`.

Bug, or by-design?

Comment: At least on StackOverflow on Japanese name of site appears only once. [Example for Twitter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENPpv.png)

Comment: I suggest a new tag [tag:status-bug-design]